# Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives (proof).

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm studying on Ahlfors, complex analysis.

Let's fix $f\colon D \subseteq \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function in the open disk $D$.

Then $\forall \,n \in \mathbb{N} \quad f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{n+1}}\,\text{d}w$ for all $z$ inside the positive-oriented circle $C$ contained in $D$.

In order to prove this statement, my textbook uses the following lemma:

$\forall \,n \in \mathbb{N} \quad \forall \,z \in D \setminus C \quad \exists \,F_n'(z)=nF_{n+1}(z)$, where $F_n(z)=\oint_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^n}\,\text{d}w$.

Let's prove it by induction.

Suppose that $\exists \,F_{n-1}'(z)=(n-1)F_n(z)$ with $z \in D \setminus C$ fixed.

Now, by using the identity $\frac{1}{(u-w)^n}=\frac{1}{(u-w)^{n-1}(u-z)}+\frac{w-z}{(u-w)^n(u-z)}$, we have:

$\forall \,w \in D \setminus C \quad \frac{F_n(w)-F_n(z)}{w-z}=\frac{1}{w-z}\left(\oint_C \frac{f(u)}{(u-w)^{n-1}(u-z)}\,\text{d}u-\oint_C \frac{f(u)}{(u-z)^{n-1}(u-z)}\,\text{d}u\right)+$

$+\oint_C \frac{f(u)}{(u-w)^n(u-z)}\,\text{d}u$.

Here I get stucked. The textbook says that the first term is equal by inductive hypotesis to $(n-1)F_{n+1}(z)$ as $w \to z$, while the second term is equal to $F_{n+1}(z)$ as $w \to z$. I really can't understand what kind of trick the book does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying from Ahlfors, we have

$\displaystyle F_n(z)-F_n(z_0)=\int_{\gamma}\frac{\varphi(\xi)d\xi}{(\xi-z)^{n-1}(\xi-z_0)}-\int_{\gamma}\frac{\varphi(\xi)d\xi}{(\xi-z_0)^n}+(z-z_0)\int_{\gamma}\frac{d\xi}{(\xi-z)^n((\xi-z_0)}.$

Write the first two terms as

$\displaystyle F_n(z)-F_n(z_0)=\int_{\gamma}\frac{\varphi(\xi)/(\xi-z_0)d\xi}{(\xi-z)^{n-1}}-\int_{\gamma}\frac{\varphi(\xi)/(\xi-z_0)d\xi}{(\xi-z_0)^{n-1}}:=G_{n-1}(z)-G_{n-1}(z_0)$

Now, divide this by $z-z_0$ and with $\varphi/(\xi-z_0)$ in place of $\varphi$, apply the inductive hypothesis to $G$ to see that $F_n'(z_0)=G_{n-1}'(z_0)=(n-1)G_n(z_0)=(n-1)F_{n+1}(z_0).$

Finally, divide the third term by $z-z_0$, and show directly that

$\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{d\xi}{(\xi-z)^n((\xi-z_0)}\to F_{n+1}(z_0)$ as $z\to z_0$.

It follows that $F_n'(z_0)=(n-1)F_{n+1}(z_0)+F_{n+1}(z_0)=nF_{n+1}(z_0).$

Comment: Thank you! My doubt is about the inductive hypotesis applied to $G$. Ahlfors make the hypotesis that $F_{n-1}'(z_0)=(n-1)F_n(z_0)$. But then it says that $G_{n-1}'(z_0)=(n-1)G_n(z_0)$. The two conditions are not equivalent, I guess.

Comment: The claim is that for $any$ continuous function $\varphi$, if $F_n(z)=\oint_C \frac{\varphi(w)}{(w-z)^n}\,\text{d}w$, then the claim is true. So it's really just a trick. $F_n$ is written as a $G_{n-1}$, to which the inductive hypothesis applies.  but they are the same function. I think all this is rather labored. There are other easier ways to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it! Where could I find an easier approach?

Comment: I believe that Conway (Functions of One Complex Variable) does it the same way as Ahlfors, but in much more detail. On the other hand, all you really need to know is that differentiation within the integral is valid. And you can do it [from scratch](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~arapura/preprints/cit.pdf).